# Google spreadsheet API throws "Unrecognized content type:application/binary"

Tags: google-api, google-sheets-api, google-data-api

Our system will check if worksheets exist or not before we insert our data to the sheet. However, some of our users will report seeing the error "Unrecognized content type:application/binary". What can be the issue?

This is the library we are using:

```
"com.google.gdata" % "core" % "1.47.1"
```

This is how we are calling it.

```
val service = new SpreadsheetService("getSpreadsheetInfo")
service.setProtocolVersion(SpreadsheetService.Versions.V3)
service.setOAuth2Credentials(
  getCredentials(accessToken, refreshToken)
)

val worksheetOpt = getWorksheets(file.getId, service).find(_.getTitle().getPlainText() == SpreadsheetConstant.SPREADSHEET_NAME).getOrElse {
  addDefaultWorksheet(file.getId, googleToken)
}

private def getWorksheets(spreadsheetId: String,
                        service: SpreadsheetService) = {
   val feed = service.getFeed(getWorksheetFeedUrl(spreadsheetId), classOf[WorksheetFeed])
                      ^^^^^^^
   feed.getEntries.asScala
 }
```

We occasionally get this following exception from getWorksheets -> service.getFeed().

```
com.google.gdata.util.ParseException: Unrecognized content type:application/binary
        at com.google.gdata.client.Service.parseResponseData(Service.java:2136) ~[com.google.gdata.core-1.47.1.jar:na]
        at com.google.gdata.client.Service.parseResponseData(Service.java:2098) ~[com.google.gdata.core-1.47.1.jar:na]
        at com.google.gdata.client.Service.getFeed(Service.java:1136) ~[com.google.gdata.core-1.47.1.jar:na]
        at com.google.gdata.client.Service.getFeed(Service.java:998) ~[com.google.gdata.core-1.47.1.jar:na]
        at com.google.gdata.client.GoogleService.getFeed(GoogleService.java:645) ~[com.google.gdata.core-1.47.1.jar:na]
        at com.google.gdata.client.Service.getFeed(Service.java:1017) ~[com.google.gdata.core-1.47.1.jar:na]
```

Comment: Which statement is causing the error? It is not listed in you stack trace

Comment: @eddyparkinson I just edited the question.

Comment: Virus ? - just that you say it is occasional and the type is binary - almost as if something is trying to inject a binary download. ... I assume you are sending the same request each time.

Comment: @eddyparkinson Yes, it is a post request. The post content will be different each time. I am not sure why you think this will be a virus.

Comment: spreadsheetId ? - The only thing that is changing AFAIK is spreadsheetId. Try logging the spreadsheetId  and see if it has anything strange in.